# Java Server for Android Application

Tags: java, android, sql-server, database, multiplayer

I need to write a server in java that will store integers that are used as stats for my android app. My app has an SQLite database that is already setup that would be useful if I could just pass those contents to the server. I need to do this so that in my multiplayer feature, a player's app will contact the server to know what level their opponent is. (This is not real time). So far I only have a TCP server that opens a client and server socket. Other than that I am not positive what I need to do to make it possible for the server to do what I need. Anyone have suggestions or good tutorials to help me with my problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you need to keep track of:

Your SQLite DB has to be used as a player session, until the player logs in as another user. To do this, you have to have one instance of the current logged in player. If you prefer other methods, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)'s a good list.

I don't think you would need a TCP connection to view the stats, instead implement a REST API in PHP or any other language for back-end that would save, update and look up for a particular player. This is a recommended method. If you are familiar with PHP, this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) will give you an idea and full details of what I mean.

Comment: Well I have a SQLite database internal to the phone that has everything I need. Basically what I want is for when the user clicks the button to begin multiplayer, for the app to automatically connect to the server which will match up the user with another player. The player they are matched with will be looked up in the database on the server so that certain values can be used on the users session. This will allow the app to do the work with figuring out the stats of what the opponent has.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, building a server has many methods. For example, You can use either socket programming or app-server. If you are familiar with web programming, jsp/php/asp.net, you can communicate between your app and server with HTTP requset, which is easy to do.
To be more specific, someone (neme:abc,password:pwd) logging in with your mutiplayer app, when he or she leaves, send the data to server with HTTP request. Then when he or she logging in with other device, you can get the data from status and continues to play. Of course, you can save the data in local with SharedPrefence in Android, too.
By the way, the apache HTTPClient is recommend when using http connection with server.